# Can anybody tell how to install gcc in m1 MacBook Air?

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

there
Actually I've recently buy an MacBook Air, And I try to install gcc on my MacBook and I've already installed VS Code on it and after I installed home brew then when I typed brew install gcc...
Then it throw an error i.e. :
zsh: command not found: Brew

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

So your trying to install something that's based on a bash script?   If so go into SysPref>User's, unlock, then right click on the Admin or Login goto advanced options and login shell. Or there's this chsh -s /bin/bash. That came from [here](https://clay-atlas.com/us/blog/2020/12/05/mac-os-en-swith-shell-script-language-zsh-bash/)

Answer (score 0):

So actually you are getting the error "zsh: command not found: Brew"
So it is not the error of gcc it means brew is not installed on your system.
First you have to install that using this cmd:
**[/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"**

After that you can run **brew install gcc** which will work fine then!

Comment: that install.sh starts with #!/bin/bash so it isn't necessary to pass it explicitly to bash.  it might be a $PATH issue, or a case-sensitivity issue?